# Hidden Markov package in Python or R

Tags: python, r, hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn

I want to build a Hidden Markov model (HMM), that must contain these properties:

> - More than one subject need to be fitted, because I make use of panel/longitudinal data
>
>   - Discrete distributions
>   - Multivariate output/emission
>   - The transition probabilities need to be a function of covariates/factors
>   - Need to impose constraints on the parameters

Does anyone know a HMM package in R or Python that has the properties?

Answer (score 0):

Try [hmmlearn](https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn). They support these 3 models

- Hidden Markov Model with Gaussian emissions.
- Hidden Markov Model with Gaussian mixture emissions.
- Hidden Markov Model with multinomial (discrete) emissions